# I want to be able to split the output of a directory and its subdirectory

Tags: powershell, directory

I want to be able to split the output of a directory and its sub directory with PowerShell. Currently this is my code:

```
Get-Childitem -path \\serverName\lettertext\Customer -Recurse -Include *.txt |
  Out-file c:\Letters\output.txt
```

This lists all the text content of the directory and subfolder.

The full directory format is:

```
\\serverName\lettertext\Customer\Client Group\Client\Client Division
```

For this reseaon I want to out the result in this format:

```
Customer| CLient Group| CLient| CLient Division| Outputs.txt
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

I changed the code, this is what I changed it to but its not working:

```
# Trying to pull a directory listing of customized letter text files
$Testing = $false
$DisplayElapsedTime = 0
[DateTime] $StartDate = Get-Date

$RootPath = "\\servername\LetterText" 

$pattern = "*.txt"
$Customer = ""
#$FileName = 'C:\letters\' + $FileName
if ($Testing -eq $false) {
    $x = Read-Host 'Customer Name'
    if ($x -ne $null) {$Customer = $x}
    $x = $null
    $x = Read-Host 'File Name (blank for all) ' 
    if ($x -ne "") {$pattern = $x}
} else {
}

if ($Customer -eq "") {
    $RequestedCustomer = " All"
    $FileName = 'LetterTextFiles ' + $StartDate.Year.ToString() +
                $StartDate.Month.ToString('00') +
                $StartDate.Day.ToString('00') + '.ltr'
} else {
    $RequestedCustomer = $Customer
    $FileName = 'LetterTextFiles ' + $StartDate.Year.ToString() +
                 $StartDate.Month.ToString('00') +
                 $StartDate.Day.ToString('00') + '--' + $Customer + '.ltr'
}
#$FileName = 'C:\util\' + $FileName
Write-Host '' | Out-File -FilePath $FileName -Encoding Default

"Requested Customer: "+ $RequestedCustomer >> $FileName 
"Requested Files: " + $pattern >> $FileName 

$Path = $RootPath + '\' +$Customer

cls
try {
    $Results = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Include:$pattern 

    if ($DisplayElapsedTime -eq -1) {
        [DateTime] $StartTime
        #'Listing Time:'
        $StartTime = Get-Date
    }
    $DirectoryName = ''
    foreach ($result in $Results) {
        if ($DirectoryName -ne $result.Directory.Name) {
            #" " >> $FileName 
            $y = ""
            $DirectoryName = $result.Directory.Name
            $FullName = $result.FullName.Replace($RootPath,'').Split('\')
            $level = $result.FullName.Replace($RootPath,'').Split('\')
            if ($result.DirectoryName -eq $RootPath) {
                $y = 'COBRAPoint base letters:'
                #Write-Host $y | Out-File -FilePath $FileName -Encoding Default 
                " " >> $FileName 
                $y >> $FileName 
            } else {
                for ($x = 0; $x -lt $level.Length -1; $x++) {
                    switch ($x) {
                        1 {$y = 'Customer: '+ $level[$x]}
                        2 {$y = ' Client Group: '+ $level[$x]}
                        3 {$y = '  Client: '+ $level[$x]}
                        4 {$y = '   Client Division: '+ $level[$x]}
                    }
                    #Write-Host $y|out-file -FilePath $FileName -Encoding Default 
                    $y >> $FileName
                }
            }
        }
        $y = "`t" + $result.Name
        #Write-Host $y | Out-File -FilePath $FileName -Encoding Default
        $y >> $FileName
        #break
    }
} catch [System.Exception] {
    $y = "No Files Found"
    $y >> $FileName
}

#Out-File $FileName

#$Output > 'out.txt'
$FileName
'Done'

if ($DisplayElapsedTime -eq -1) {
    'Total Time:'
    New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End (Get-Date)
}
```

Comment: What is the "output of a directory"?

Comment: Taking a bit of a guess here, but do you want to output the result of each folder into a separate file, based on the name of the folder?

Comment: Basically the parent directory contains sub directory which contains txt files or another subdirectory which contains files or another sub directory which contains files..

Comment: For example, this is an output of the script:   Directory: \\serverName\lettertext\Customer\Client Group

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                     
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                     
-a---         11/6/2013   2:39 PM       5167 COBRATermination.txt

Comment: SO basic instead of labeling the result as \\server\customer\etc\etc...I want it to just output the result as: Customer  CLient Group  Client CLient Division and then the text file. All formatted without having to reformat the output when I paste it in excel.

Answer (score 2):

One option:

```
Get-Childitem -path \\serverName\lettertext\Customer -Recurse -Include *.txt |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Parts = $_.fullname.split('\')[4..7]
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Customer = $Parts[0]
            ClientGroup = $Parts[1]
            Client = $Parts[2]
            ClientDivision = $Parts[3]
            FileName = $_.FullName | Split-Path -Leaf
        }
} | Export-Csv c:\somedir\clientfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for this, added a curly brace. No information is being returned for the customer, ClientGroup, CLient and CLientDivision. I am looking into this.

Comment: I had a typo in the first version I posted, using $parts[4] to $parts[7] in the object hash.  Should have been $parts[0] to $parts[3].It's been fixed in the answer, but it would have produced that result originally.

Comment: Still don't know why it's not returning the subfolders the .txt files are located in.

Comment: Got it to work! Had to restructure the folder; that was pretty much all I did and I get the needed output, but text files still populate in the wrong column but I can manually fix that. Thanks a lot! You rock!

Comment: You're welcome.  And thanks to @Anthony Stringer for the edit.  His solution would probably work too (didn't test it), but I thought the simple text split would be easier to follow.

Comment: thanks for providing this - i like this line of thought, and i think it reads better.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyStringer you were awesome too!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$folder = 'c:\temp'
$customer = Split-Path $folder -Leaf
Get-Childitem -Path $folder -Recurse -Include *.txt | % {
    $sub = ($_.fullname -replace [regex]::Escape($folder)).trim('\')
    $split = $sub.split('\')
    if ($split.count -eq 4) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Customer = $customer
            ClientGroup = $split[0]
            Client = $split[1]
            ClientDivision = $split[2]
            File = $split[3]
        }
    }
} | epcsv c:\Letters\output.csv -not
```